# How can I know when gallery refresh is finished?

Tags: android

I use:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

for refreshing my gallery, but how can I know when it finished refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confess I have not tried this but the `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED` broadcast looks like it might help you.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED